# How to solve $\frac{2s^s}{(1-s)^{1-s}}\leq 3$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

How to compute that
$$\sup_s\{s\geq 1: \log \frac{2s^s(1-s)}{(1-s)^s}\leq \log 3\}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the function $$f(s)=\frac{2s^s}{(1-s)^{1-s}}$$ you have
$$f'(s)=2 (1-s)^{s-1} s^s (\log (1-s)+\log (s)+2)$$ which is zero when
$$\log (1-s)+\log (s)+2=0 \implies s(1-s)=e^{-2}\implies s\pm=\frac{1}{2}\pm
\frac{\sqrt{e^2-4}}{2 e}$$

Use the second derivative test to show that $s_-$ corresponds to a minimum and $s_+$ to a maximum.

Now
$$f(s_+)=2 e^{-\frac{\sqrt{e^2-4}}{e}} \sqrt{\frac{e+\sqrt{e^2-4}}{e-\sqrt{e^2-4}}}\approx 2.31615$$